# Azure SQL API vs Azure Mongo API

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm very new in the world of "NoSQL", Recently I started using Cosmos DB for JSON documents and am able to store and get data using CosmosDB "SQL" and "Mongo" API.

Which API is best for me? (requirement: Performance, Low Latency, Huge Collection, Low cost)

Comment: There's simply no way to offer an objective answer to this. You'll need to look at both API surfaces to see which fits your application the best. We don't know anything about your app, the shape of your data, the types of queries needed, etc.

Comment: I'm using Cosmos DB for an enterprise application, As usual, need to write a complex query to get for reporting

Comment: As usual? Not sure what that means. But... "Complex query" is vague, and there's nothing you've provided here that shows any difficulty creating your complex query. Maybe consider editing your question to show the input and output you're trying to derive from your query, along with the query itself, and where you're getting stuck... Other than that, there's really nothing that can be said here. On top of that, impossible to guess at latency and query cost, without you running your queries and examining the RU cost yourself.

Comment: @DavidMakogon As of now, I'm a very initial face of development and limited knowledge of NoSQL. I'm able to achieve result from both API(SQL & Monga). I really don't know how complex query need to write in future.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Now I have spent more than 6 months with Cosmos DB project. I can give my opinion on this question.

Azure Cosmos DB offer the same feature with SQL API vs Mongo API, hence you can't compare by feature.

**Reason using Mongo API in Cosmos DB**

1. If you have existing Mongo DB database and you want to migrate on Azure.
2. If you or your team members have Mongo DB experience.
3. If you are developing cloud agnostic application, you can move your application on-premise or any other cloud vendor.

**Reason using SQL API in Cosmos DB**

1. If you have SQL query experience, it would be easy to start.
2. If you are not looking cloud agnostic application. (can't move Cosmos DB application on-premise or other clouds vendors).
3. Cosmos DB [Change Feed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed) only available with SQL API.

**--- UPDATED 2020 ---**

[Change Feed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed) is available for all the APIs across all available SDKs except the Table API

Comment: Additional argument - to date the Mongo DB API is lacking support for the Retry (e.g. in case HTTP 429 is issued when established throughput limits are surpassed) support. The SQL API does support this nativelly.

Comment: ChangeFeed is now available using the Mongo API as well: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-change-streams

Comment: Please update the Point no. 3 as Change Feed is now available for all except Table API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed

Answer (score 6):

Both the API’s provide you high throughput, low latency, elastic scale, geo-replication, etc.

It boils down to what you are comfortable with. Many people preferred Mongo, as they are already familiar with Mongo, it’s syntax, tools, and they already had an application built on Mongo which they migrated to CosmosDB.

If you are starting new, and don’t have an existing investment in Mongo, I will suggest starting with SQL. SQL is the oldest API of CosmosDB, and more battle hardened.

Comment: agree with you, both API definitely have Pros. Cons (i.e. helper method etc.)  I want to know that

Comment: I really don't see how one API can be recommended over another, especially when nothing is known about the OP's app and related requirements. There's no way to know what types of queries will be run (and what they'll cost), what frameworks will be used (e.g. Mongoose which mandates MongoDB), need for specific aggregations (which MongoDB API provides), etc.

Comment: After talking directly with someone on the cosmos team, if starting from scratch they recommend the SQL API because they control all in-house development end-to-end. At what point can you recommend something to someone?  If you know nothing about the OP you can still recommend SQLAPI for this alone.  It's up to the OP to shift that recommendation.  If the OP wants to build out a 'full-stack' mongo solution the recommendation is to not use cosmos at all.  If they provide even further info then the recommendation will shift.  With little information for a 'new' user? SQL API is recommended.

Answer (score 5):

As a software engineer using MongoDB API. I can confirm that my team and I suffered when handling 426 code errors from CosmosDB. So we end up developing our own custom solution with Polly to handles these throttles. Whereas if we used SQL API we would have access to [CosmosDB](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB/) sdk  which pretty much handles these situations. This is just my feedback.